# Set request context to a default value

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In Django, whenever I need to access `messages` or the `user` instance, I need to do this:

```
return render_to_response('news.html', {"articles": articles}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Is there any way to make this default behavior? This is part of my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
```

I don't want to specify the context_instance whenever I want to render a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.3+ you can use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead:

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a
>   context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.